# Upgrade to Python 2.6.5 on mac

Tags: python, macos

I'd like to upgrade to Python 2.6.5 on Mac.

I've seen [this question on how to upgrade to 2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541776/upgrade-python-to-2-6-on-mac) using macports, but it only talks about how to get 2.6 - I need 2.6.5 specifically, I currently have 2.6.1 installed.

Please could someone advise?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to use the macports version -- just use the official framework build from http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.6.5/

(Note that there's a 2.6.6 version now.)

Answer (score 0):

`port install python26 @2.6.5`