# Scrapy, problems on the tutorial

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, twisted, scrapy

Ive been trying to get around Scrapy.

I have python 2.7 installed on my mac (OSX 10.8.5) from before, so I installed pip, scrapy, lxml and twisted (I did the last one manually though through dmg file).

I try to run `scrapy startproject tutorial` to no success I only get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/scrapy", line 3, in <module>
    from scrapy.cmdline import execute
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    from twisted import version as _txv
ImportError: No module named twisted
```

Now I've looked around for hours can't seem to find what the problem is, so I thought I'd give this here a shot, any suggestions?

pJ

Comment: What does `pip list` give you? (Why did you install twisted manually?)

Answer (score 1):

You [might be better off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869315/python-2-7-1-cant-see-twisted) setting up a virtualenv and installing twisted with pip instead.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error. Works if you install twisted manually, then uninstall scrappy and

```
reinstall
pip install twisted
pip uninstall scrapy
pip install scrapy
```